# Django: Trying to catch ValidationErrors and return results as boolean

Tags: django

I don't understand why this try/except isn't working.

I have a validation method that might raise a `ValidationError` (one of several).  However, in another method that renames a schema, I want to catch all those errors in favor of one generic message.

The validation method (edited for brevity):

```
def validate_tenant_schema_name(tenant, value):
    if {some invalid condition in schema name}:
        raise ValidationError('Schema name may not be blank.')

    if {some other invalid condition in schema name}:
        raise ValidationError('Schema name may not begin or end with an underscore.')

    if {yet another invalid condition in schema name}:
        raise ValidationError('Schema name must have 2 to 30 characters.')

    return name
```

My validation "wrapper" method:

```
def is_valid_schema_name(name):
    try:
        _ = validate_tenant_schema_name(None, name)
        return True
    except ValidationError:        # Debug got here
        return False               # but didn't get here
```

My schema_rename method:

```
def schema_rename(tenant, new_schema_name):
    if schema_exists(new_schema_name):
        raise ValidationError("New schema name already exists")
    if not is_valid_schema_name(new_schema_name):
        raise ValidationError("Invalid string used for the schema name.")
    ...run the sql to rename the schema...
    tenant.save()
```

When I stepped through it in debug, it got to the `except` in the `is_valid` method, but didn't get to the `return False` - as noted by the comments in the `is_valid` method.  It just returned to the calling method.

I also evaluated the expression `is_valid_schema_name(new_schema_name)` in my debugger.  If I give it a valid schema name, it returns `True`.  If I give it an invalid name, it returns `Nonetype`.

I also tried this version of the `is_valid` method, thinking that perhaps returning False while still in the exception handler might be messing it up, but I got the same results.

```
def is_valid_schema_name(name):
    try:
        _ = validate_tenant_schema_name(None, name)
        return True
    except ValidationError:
        pass
    return False
```

Can someone shed some light on this issue?

Comment: did you  try using variable name instead of underscore and binding it to a variable like except ValidationError as e:

Comment: Isn't using an underscore for assignment the convention for a throw-away value (not needed in the method)?

I'll try assigning the exception to "e" and see if I can print it.

Comment: So I changed the except to "except ValidationError as e", and right under that, added "print(e)", but it still just returns from the except statement back to the calling method. It never gets to the print(e).

Comment: Strange... when I let it run through (instead of stopping in debug), it gets one of the errors from the validation method.  It's like those aren't being caught by the "try/except", though I can see it going to the except statement in debug.

Comment: Would  you  specify which debug method  are you  following. Is it pdb ?

Comment: I'm using Intellij IDEA, and our project is in a Docker setup.